# Find all classes defined in scope of script

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got a bunch of javascript files that are included in the main html via simple

```
<script src ="script.js"></script> 
<script defer src ="anotherscript.js"></script>
```

script.js defines a range of es6 classes like

```
class TestPong1 { 
  doSomething() {
    // doSomething
  }
}

class TestPong2 { 
  doSomethingElse() {
    // doSomethingElse
  }
}
```

anotherscript.js should be able to dynamically find all classes defined previously, create them and execute the methods one after another.

Unfortunately I am already stuck with the first problem: How to get the names of all classes specified "above" anotherscript.js. I tried `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);` which works well for functions but not for classes.

Wanted idea:

```
function findAllClassNamesInScope() {
    // ??? should return list of classes in scope. eg ['TestPong1',  'TestPong2']
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are these classes wrapped in a module?

Comment: No. In my case not. Simple plain javascript loaded by the browser...

Comment: Do you have an option to wrap it in a function or an object? If yes, you can use this wrapper to access all function. If not, then it would be difficult

Comment: It seems like the main issue here is this just isn't something you should be tying to do. If you have content in multiple files, you should either be using a module loader that would export a known set of things, or file should be creating its own namespace that can be inspected, e.g. `window.RaNamespace.TestPong1 = class TestPong1 {}` so you can do `Object.keys(window.RaNamespace)`.

Comment: So there is no "easy" way to get all classes similar to Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this); Right? I could parse the script myself and extract class names subsequently as proposed in the answer - but that'd involve fetching the script two times, and also parsing the file which sounds error - prone. Correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score -1):

You can select the previous `script` element, use `fetch()` to request the `script`, parse `.text()` response, call `window.eval` on result of splitting text, iterate array at `for..of` loop, call each `class` with `new` operator

```
let scripts = document.scripts;
let script = scripts[scripts.length - 2];
fetch(script.src)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(script => {
  let classes = script.split(/\s(?=class)/).map(window.eval);
  for (let fn of classes) {
    console.log(fn.name, new fn())
  }
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/745xXOinKhRkFYPN7nno?p=preview

Comment: Hey! That's a pretty cool idea! Could you think of something more "direct" - similar to Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this); but for classes? aka "Object.getDefinedClasses(this);" or such..?

Comment: Chain `.map(({name}) => name)` to `classes` array.